# Error using DynamicReports: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ELEMENT_GROUP_HEIGHT

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I am using the latest version of DynamicReports, and I am getting the following error:

```
Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/home/diego.queres/Desenv/Java/Projetos%20Java/VAGAS/ProcessadorRelatoriosJasper/dist/run4454548/lib/dynamicreports-examples-4.1.1.jar!/net/sf/dynamicreports/examples/genericelement/openflashchart/openflashchart.xml]
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: ELEMENT_GROUP_HEIGHT
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ConstantTransform.stretchType(ConstantTransform.java:1072)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ComponentTransform.component(ComponentTransform.java:190)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ComponentTransform.component(ComponentTransform.java:116)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ComponentTransform.list(ComponentTransform.java:248)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.ComponentTransform.component(ComponentTransform.java:112)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.BandTransform.band(BandTransform.java:132)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.BandTransform.transform(BandTransform.java:58)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.transformation.JasperTransform.transform(JasperTransform.java:81)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperReportDesign(JasperReportBuilder.java:269)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.getJasperParameters(JasperReportBuilder.java:296)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toJasperPrint(JasperReportBuilder.java:307)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:634)
    at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toXlsx(JasperReportBuilder.java:607)
```

This error occurs when I call `JasperReportBuilder.toXlsx()`.

My source code:

```
JasperReportBuilder report = report();
List<TextColumnBuilder> lsColumns = getDRColumnsFromRecordset(rs);
for (TextColumnBuilder tcbColumn : lsColumns) {
    report.addColumn(tcbColumn);
}
report.title(cmp.text("Title")); 
report.pageFooter(cmp.pageXofY());      
report.ignorePageWidth();
report.ignorePagination();
report.setDataSource(rs);
report.toXlsx(xlsxExporter);   //throw error in this line
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution to the problem. After several testing the dependencies of Dynamic Reports, i could get the solution.

I'm using JasperReports 6.1.0 in my application. It generates reports from Jasper templates (jrxml). I decided to add the resource to generate reports without jrxml using Dynamic Reports.

The version I was using Dynamic Reports is the version 4.1.1, the latest. I looked all versions (which are available on Source Forge: https://sourceforge.net/projects/dynamicreports/files/dynamicreports), and realized that this version uses JasperReports version 6.2.2.
so I tried a Dynamic Reports version who use by default JasperReports 6.1.0. : **Dynamic Reports version 4.0.1.**

Now it is working!

**What can we learn from this is that: Is important to check the JasperReports version your Dynamic Reports uses, so there is no incompatibility problems.**